# Expression-bodied members vs Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-body

> A lambda expression is a block of code (an expression or a statement block) that is treated as an object. It can be passed as an argument to methods, and it can also be returned by method calls.

```
(input parameters) => expression
 SomeFunction(x => x * x);
```

Looking this statement I was wondering what's the difference when using lambdas and when using Expression-bodied?

```
public string Name => First + " " + Last;
```

Comment: One is a delegate and the other is a property.

Comment: I believe `Name => ""` will implicitly become a `get return` statement

Comment: When lambda expressions were first introduced, they could be used to represent either an in-line delegate or an _expression_.  Delegates are like function pointers when you _invoke_ a delegate, you call the code that the delegate represents.  An expression represents abstract code.  When you use Linq2SQL or Entity Framework, the lambda you using in a _where clause_ represents predicate code that doesn't execute in the context of your C# program, it represents code that gets executed on the database server.  So, an _expression body_ represents abstract code, in this case used to impl the prop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expression bodied methods are syntactic sugar. Instead of writing this:

```
public string GetName()
{
    return First + " " + Last;
}
```

you can just write this:

```
public string GetName() => First + " " + Last;
```

and the result of calling either the first or the second would be exactly the same.

The same is true also for all the kinds of [expression body members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

On the other hand, a lambda expressions as it is stated formally [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) is:

> an **anonymous function** that you can use to
>   create *delegates or expression tree types*.

That being said it is clear that despite the similarity in syntax, there are two completely different things.

Answer (score 14):

The expression-bodied syntax is really only a shorter syntax for properties and (named) methods and has no special meaning. In particular, it has nothing to do with lambda expressions.

These two lines are totally equivalent:

```
public string Name => First + " " + Last;

public string Name { get { return First + " " + Last; } }
```

You can also write expression-bodied methods (note the difference to your lambda expression doing the same. Here you specify an optional access modifier, a return type and a name):

```
public int Square (int x) => x * x;
```

instead of

```
public int Square (int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

You can also use it to write getters and setters

```
private string _name;
public Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => _name = value;
}
```

and for constructors (assuming a class named `Person`):

```
public Person(string name) => _name = name;
```

Using the tuple syntax, you can even assign several parameters

```
public Person(string first, string last) => (_first, _last) = (first, last);
```

This works for assigning to properties as well.

Comment: Yeah.  In a way, it's kind of a shame that they co-opted the lambda operator for this.

Comment: I agree  that it can be confusing.