# What => means in property declaration (not a lambda expression)?

Tags: c#

```
public override double TotalSpecialPower => 1000;
```

What does the `=>` operator mean?

I know that `=>` is a lambda expression, but I don't know what it means in `public override double TotalSpecialPower => 1000;`.

And also can anyone explain to me the `get` and `set` and how they work in the following code?

```
private int _health = 100;
public int Health
{
    get => _health;
    set { _health = value; CaluateHeath(); }
}
```

Comment: @RaymondChen That QA refers to a lambda or anonymous method, not to expression-bodied members which the OP is referring to.

Comment: @Dai I was going to edit the duplicate list, but your reopen now blocked me. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098375/expression-bodied-members-vs-lambda-expressions

Comment: I appreciate both of you for the answers.

Answer (score 9):

`=>` is used for lambda-functions as you mentioned. It's also used for expression-bodied members.

The documentation on expression-bodied members is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

- C# 6.0 in 2015 added support for expression-bodied methods.
- C# 7.0 in 2016 added support for expression-bodied properties and other members.
- In methods and property `get` blocks, it's equivalent to `{ return X; }`.
- In properties:

  - If the property has a single expression-body, then it's equivalent to declaring a getter-only `get { return X; }` property.
  - If the property has `get => X`, then it's also equivalent to `get { return X; }` but also allows you to define a `set` too.
  - If the property has `set => X = value;` then it's equivalent to `set { X = value; }`

So this:

```
public int Health
{
    get => _health;
    set { _health = value; CaluateHeath(); }
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public int Health
{
    get { return _health };
    set { _health = value; CaluateHeath(); }
}
```

And this:

```
public override double TotalSpecialPower => 1000;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public override double TotalSpecialPower
{
    get { return 1000; }
}
```

And this (note the parentheses):

```
public override double TotalSpecialPower() => 1000;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public override double TotalSpecialPower()
{
    return 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s all about Expression Bodies. Properties are just syntactic sugar to make method calls look like normal field assignments and gets.

A normal property had a get and set with curly backs to a block of code. That can be a lot of syntax for a one liner. So, in the most recent versions of the C# language, you can use Expression Bodies (fat arrows), like with lambdas, for your getters and setters.

I hope that helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members