# c# Main() function in .net core console apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda, console

I'm just learning .NET Core and I'm trying to make sense of the way the `Main()` function is coded.  When I see code examples of .NET core prorgrams, this is what I see:

```cs
static Task Main(string[] args) => 
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

My questions are:

1. Why return a type of `Task` from the `Main()`, and how/where is a type of `Task` being instantiated?  Is this something done in the background by the framework?
2. Why use a lambda expression for the body of the `Main()` function?  From all the documentation I've read about Lambda expressions, they are used either for delegates or expression trees.  Neither of those are present here.

Comment: For 2. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members . TL;DR it's syntactic sugar when you only have one statement in your method block.

Comment: For 1. it allows you to make your Main method async so you can use await.

Comment: @Chronicle The method is neither `async` nor does it use `await`.

Comment: @Chronicle Expression bodied members must be implemented with an expression, not a statement, hence the name *expression* bodied members.

Answer (score 2):

Explanations for both:

1. Look at the c# 7.1 specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main

> Allow await to be used in an application's Main / entrypoint method by allowing the entrypoint to return Task / Task and be marked async.

Example usage:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

class Test
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args) =>
        Console.WriteLine(await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(args[0]));
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that:

- (1) If `await` isn't used inside Main(), it can return `Task` without being marked as `async`.
- (2) When Main() returns `Task`, the compiler generates a new entry point

> `static Task Main()` results in the compiler emitting the equivalent of `private static void $GeneratedMain() => Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/main-return-values#compiler-generated-code).

2. The lambda is an expression-bodied member. These are syntactic sugar for simpler expressions.

> Expression body definitions let you provide a member's implementation in a very concise, readable form.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Example

```
public void DisplayName() => Console.WriteLine(ToString());
```

The difference with lamdas is here: [Expression-bodied members vs Lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098375/expression-bodied-members-vs-lambda-expressions)